# Как изменить размер спрайта directx 9?

Tags: c++, directx

Как в directx 9 можно сменить размер спрайта ?
Точней растянуть его на все окно программы.
Ибо создаю текстуру и в размере ставлю вот эти параметры:

```
case WM_SIZE:
int nWidth = LOWORD(lParam);
int nHeight = HIWORD(lParam);
```

Но когда рандерю спрайт с этой текстурой он почему то получается то больше (если растянуть окно) окна то меньше(если сжать окно).